# Буквальное значение слова "преклонный"

Tags: этимология, лексика, идиомы

В речи я встречал это слово только в составе устойчивого словосочетания "преклонный возраст" как эвфемизма слова "старость" (например, вместо "старик" - "мужчина преклонного возраста").

Словарь Ушакова опять-таки упоминает это слово только в контексте возраста:

> **ПРЕКЛО́ННЫЙ**, преклонная, преклонное (книжн.). Перешагнувший через зрелые года, приближающийся к глубокой старости, к смерти (о возрасте).

Однако корень слова - "клон", т. е. тот же, что в словах "клонить", "склонять", "преклонять". Отсюда появляются два вопроса:

1. Как слово "преклонный" соотносится с "преклонять", "преклоняющийся"? Каким может быть буквальный смысл этого слова? "Преклонный" перед кем (чем)?
2. Если "преклонный возраст" - приближающийся к смерти (ср. "на склоне лет"), почему это выражение употребляется как "мягкий" вариант для обозначения старости? Вежливая форма - "мужчина преклонного возраста", но никогда не "мужчина на склоне лет" или "мужчина, которому недолго осталось", хотя по смыслу должно быть одно и то же.

Answer (score 2):

Вот [здесь](http://etymolog.ruslang.ru/vinogradov.php?id=preklonnij&vol=3) посмотрите. Хотя на главный вопрос там, пожалуй, ответа нет. Почему именно "преклонный". Мне всегда казалось, что речь идет о "преклонении колен" перед старшими. Но, просмотрев различные источники и обсуждения на форумах, пришла к выводу, что все-таки "клонящийся, стремящийся к закату (даже смерти)".

Comment: "Преклонный старик" я, кстати, никогда не слышал. Только "преклонные года/лета", "преклонный возраст".

Comment: Потому Виноградов и называет его не вполне лексически сочетаемым. Мне лично в повседневной речи тоже не попадалось. За художественную литературу не ручаюсь.

Answer (score 2):

Буквально преклонный - склонённый. Остаток значения фразеологизм "на склоне дней". Общеславянский корень клон-низ. Клонить - пригибать книзу.Пре-старославянская приставка со значением превосходства: пре+ клонный = очень склонённый. Отсюда устаревшее употребление слова "преклонный старик"-такой старый, что согнулся к земле (из земли вышли - в землю уйдём), т.е. близкий к смерти. Потом останется только связанное употребление: преклонные годы - идущие под уклон, к концу, к закату жизни, чтобы кануть в Лету.

В "Словаре церковнославянского и русского языка" 1847 г. преклонный -  "приближающийся к концу" (о возрасте и летах)  По тому же пути идет и словарь под ред. Д. Н. Ушакова: "Преклонный, -ая, -ое (книжн.). Перешагнувший через зрелые года, приближающийся к глубокой старости, к смерти (о возрасте)"